# tt_news - Force plugin to start at a particular id

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In earlier versions of the tt_news plugin there was some configuration in the flex form which allowed you to force a start id for the plugin.
**List StartId: Force LIST or LATEST to start from this item [deprecated]**

In newer versions this is not possible.  I haven't had a problem with this so far however I now want to have three plugins on the page. A latest and two lists.

The Latest and first list plugin will be linked and rotate through the 4 latest articles using the jquery cycle plugin.

However further down the page I have more news where I want to show article 5-12.  Because I have already used `plugin.tt_news{excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews = 0}` so that I could rotate the top two plugins

The third plugin (second list is showing article 1-8 but I need it to show 5-12).  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get around this problem?  I have considered IFraming 5-12 from a blank page which would work but obviously wouldn't be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute this option with the extension [ttnews_selectconf](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ttnews_selectconf). Check the [TypoScript options](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/ttnews_selectconf/0.2.3/view/1/4/#c1608): The "**begin**" and "**max**" parameters should be the right choice:

```
plugin.tt_news {
  extensions {
    ttnews_selectconf {
      begin = 5
      max = 7
    }
  }
}
```